# Unknown prop on Component that is capitalized

Tags: reactjs, components, prop

I'm getting the following error:

`` warning.js:35 Warning: Unknown prop `notification` on <NotificatonType.InvitedToEventNotification> tag. Remove this prop from the element. ``

I get it that this happens when transferring props which are not standard on a dom element, however here I'm trying to use my own component. Here is the render method:

```
render() {
    const type = this.props.notification.type;

    let Tag = "NotificatonType." + type;

    return <Tag {...this.props}/>
}
```

Comment: I believe that React 16 removes this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line:

`let Tag = "NotificatonType." + type;`

You need to pass a React custom element, not a string with the class/function name. This way to React it looks like a DIV or similar.

You could probably do this instead:

`let Tag = NotificationType[type]` but without seeing you NotificationType code is hard to figure.